# AWS Beanstalk Node js deployment issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi I am trying to deploy node js app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However I am not able to deploy the same. Every-time the build fails.

Getting below error:

```
During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
```

Sharing part of package.json for reference.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "debug": "ndb server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "mocha --recursive --timeout 20000 --exit",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

Comment: you need a `build` script in package.json there is no build command.

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for the suggestion. Can you please help me understand how shall I go about it.

Comment: That log is not especially helpful. You might find more useful info if you go to logs-> request logs -> last 100 lines Then look at web-stout.log(or something like that), that might reveal the exact error.

Comment: Hi I am getting..below error @SelloMkantjwa.. Cn you please help with the same

Comment: CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: 'npm' failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1647882425,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1647882425,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

Comment: @sgrmhdk instead of last 100 lines select "all logs" and look at th en-engine.loh file. There'll be more info there. R u installing private dependencies by any chance?